# Checking out repository on work group computers

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have created a local repository and its `URL is file:///F:/subversion/MyProject` And I checked out MyProject to my local machine....it works fine..

But when I try to CheckOut on a WorkGroup Computer using

`URL: file:///Server_Name/F:/subversion/MyProject` .. it gives an error like

Error: Unable to open an ra_local session to url.

Error: Unable to open repository `file:///Server_Name/F:/subversion/MyProject`

I also tried `Server_Name/file:///F:/subversion/MyProject`

Secondly,

I have shared the folder subversion(with same sharename--subversion) on F: drive and I use the `URL: \\servername\subversion\MyProject` but still it gives same error Any clues ??

Answer (score 0):

I think, you chose incorrect way to share repository. Try to use [this manual](http://hamrotechtips.blogspot.com/2008/03/setup-of-local-lan-svn-server.html). It is for Unix, but on Windows procedure must be the same.